# mouseDown not detected for my NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, nsimageview, mousedown

I've been searching for answers to this question and while I have done the steps I still cannot seem to get the mouseDown method to be called.
What I want is when the user clicks and holds down on the image, it should print out "Mouse down!".
(Eventually what I want to do is the user to click and hold on the image to cause a sound to play, and when they let go the sound will stop).

Here's what I have. My header:

```
@interface MyNSImageView : NSImageView <NSImageDelegate> {
}
@end
```

And my class:

```
@implementation MyNSImageView

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {

     if ([[self target] respondsToSelector:[self action]]) {
     [NSApp sendAction:[self action] to:[self target] from:self];
     }
    NSLog(@"Mouse Down!");
}

@end
```

Does this look right? If so, then are there other problems which might be interfering with it? Of not, what should I do?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thought: Try implementing `acceptsFirstResponder` and return yes. Then have your delegate set the first responder to the image view....

UPDATE:

So, I just created a new project, and added a class MyClass to it, which inherits from NSImageView. mouseDown is implemented:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
NSLog(@"Mouse Down");
}
```

and initWithFrame is implemented:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        NSURL *newURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForImageResource:@"ARandomImageIAddedtoProject"];
        NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
        [self setImage:newImage];
    }

return self;
}
```

To make the view visible.

I then edited the nib file by adding a custom class to the window, and changing the class of the custom class to MyClass. It worked fine, so I dunno whats wrong.

Comment: I have just done so, but still nothing is being printed out. I have made two buttons - would that interfere with the initFirstResponder? (even though I only have one as the first responder)

Comment: Hah - I may have figured out why. My xib file isn't updating when I change it. I'm using Xcode 4 - got any ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: I dunno - Are you saving the xib file after editing it? Do you have permission to edit the file? Other than that I dunno whats wrong. I'm updating my answer with my test..

Comment: Solved - I was editing the wrong xib file... -headdesk- Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

Add an **invisible button** without border or title above the NSImageView.

:)

Comment: `[button setTransparent:YES];`